# To, in, at or into the Past?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, prepositions

If we want to find something or understand something from the Past, what's correct to say?

Do we look **to the Past**, **in the Past**, **at the Past** or **into the Past**?

What is the difference between the four:

- I would look **into** the past to see if there happened any situations of the kind.
- If you journey **to** the past you may find very interesting sources of information.
- You might want to search for the answer **in** your past.
- If we have a look **at** the past we can see the changes to our civilization over the years.

Comment: You can start by checking [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=look+to+the+past%2C+look+into+the+past%2C+look+in+the+past&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clook%20to%20the%20past%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clook%20into%20the%20past%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clook%20in%20the%20past%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: I did already. what is the difference then?

Comment: You should look for some example sentences using the phrases, and then add them to you question and ask if the difference is not clear. All can be used in some context or another.

Comment: Anybody here for an answer?

Answer (score -2):

1. The 'past' is not an active provider of understanding. We 'look to' active providers.
2. & 4. The 'past' is not a container for other things. We 'look in/into' containers of some sort.
3. Is the best choice for this particular situation (regarding the past.)

A related use of 'look at/look into' involves more specific situations. For example, a prosecutor might 'look at' a past situation where the facts are already available or 'look into' a past situation where the facts must be searched for and investigated for.